# sending file from the back end to a WS rest full java-8

Tags: java, rest, http-headers, httpresponse

I recieve uploaded file in my controller, and i want to upload it to another database passing by a web service.

**web service ressource :**

```
@Path("/upload")
public class UploadResource {
        
    @POST
    @Path("/test")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response testUpload(Multipart multipart) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(null).build();
    }   
    
}
```

**Controller core function :**

```
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    restTemplate.setErrorHandler(this.responseHandler);

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
    headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA));
```

How can I upload the file and read it in my web service ?

Thank you.